# UIColor is not giving the intended color

Tags: ios

I wanted to set a the navigation bar tint color to RGB(255,80,30) as shown in the attached image. But when I execute the simulator, I get a different color.
[image: Photoshop color properties comparison]

Here is my code in the view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIColor *backgroundColor = [Theme colorProperty:BACKGROUND_COLOR
                                        fromTabMenu:CALENDAR];
    CGFloat redvalue, greenvalue, bluevalue, alphavalue;
    [backgroundColor getRed:&redvalue green:&greenvalue blue:&bluevalue alpha:&alphavalue];

    NSLog(@"red:%f, green:%f, blue:%f, alpha:%f", redvalue*255.0, greenvalue*255.0, bluevalue*255.0, alphavalue*255.0);

    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:backgroundColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:backgroundColor];
}
```

and I get the following value in the console output.

```
2014-03-14 04:37:49.404 planner[46712:70b] red:255.000000, 
                                         green:80.000003, 
                                          blue:30.000000, 
                                         alpha:255.000000
```

As you can see, I have set the correct R G B value, but I can not get the intended color. What is the problem here?

Comment: Just as an experiment set your `UIView` to this `[UIColor colorWithRed:1.000000F green:0.313725F blue:0.117647F alpha:1.0F]` thats the exact RGB you are looking for, the reason I say the `UIView` as there is no styling or tint's applied there and you can determine if photoshops colour settings are different to iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the time @sbarow. I get the wrong color for the view background too. Why is this happening?

Comment: I am no expert on this but I know that Photoshop can be setup for different mediums (publishing, web, devices etc) which have different colour settings, maybe look into that. Get `Color Maker` on the app store to confirm your colors.

Comment: @sbarow You are great. Thanks for the help. I would like to give you the credit. but you did not answer my question. If you can answer the question, I will pick your answer.

Comment: Posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an experiment set your `UIView` to this `[UIColor colorWithRed:1.000000F green:0.313725F blue:0.117647F alpha:1.0F]` thats the exact RGB you are looking for, the reason I say the UIView as there is no styling or tint's applied there and you can determine if photoshops colour settings are different to iOS.

**Update**

Setting background to the RBG colour did not render the same colour displayed by photoshop.

**Update 2**

I am no expert on this but I know that Photoshop can be setup for different mediums (publishing, web, devices etc) which have different colour settings, maybe look into that. Get `Color Maker` on the app store to confirm your colors.

[Color Maker](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/color-maker/id561995913?mt=12)

Answer (score 3):

Set your navigation bar to be not translucent. Your viewDidLoad method should look like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIColor *backgroundColor = [Theme colorProperty:BACKGROUND_COLOR
                                        fromTabMenu:CALENDAR];
    CGFloat redvalue, greenvalue, bluevalue, alphavalue;
    [backgroundColor getRed:&redvalue green:&greenvalue blue:&bluevalue alpha:&alphavalue];

    NSLog(@"red:%f, green:%f, blue:%f, alpha:%f", redvalue*255.0, greenvalue*255.0, bluevalue*255.0, alphavalue*255.0);

    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:backgroundColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:backgroundColor];

    // Set to NOT translucent.
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the background color instead of tint color?

Comment: Nope my mistake. When I set the same color in storyboard, it works but I need to set this color in code.

Comment: Whether you do it in code or interface builder, the result should be the same. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: It seems the photoshop color picker was giving me incorrect information because the PSD image was stored in RGB/8bit. Sorry for all the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The color appears lighter because the navigation bar most likely has the `translucent` property set to `YES` (the default behavior in iOS 7). Because it's slightly transparent, the color looks lighter when presented in front of a white background. To fix, set `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO`